# rsyslog 8.x configuration to store remote logs into different folder base on host on centos 7

Tags: centos7, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog to do the testing, rsyslog version rsyslog-8.24.0-34.el7.x86_64

I found myself having trouble to configure rsyslog to work for me.

My requirement is simple: consolidate all my linux server syslog into one centralised syslog server.

Most of the tutorials I found on the internet are out of dated, and I have found old syntax configuration are not supported anymore.

I am trying to config it to store remote syslog into "%HOSTNAME%/log_{date}.log" .

Referred to this tutorial https://www.tecmint.com/create-centralized-log-server-with-rsyslog-in-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#### EXTERNAL LOG SOURCES ####
$template RemoteHost,"/var/log/remote-hosts/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%-%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%.log" 
if ($hostname != '<ServerName>') then ?RemoteHost 
& ~
```

...I get a parse error about `& ~` but stop appears to break the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found rsyslog quite complex to configure and make it work. It's more easier to just deploy a golang based syslog service.

Reference here:
https://github.com/mcuadros/go-syslog/tree/v2.3.0